# How to fetch node in XML using Java?

Tags: java, xml

I want to fetch value of the node `ServerVersion`

```
<result>
<response id="27mSTG">
<routing>
<configs>
<linqmap.routing.RoutingServerConfig>
<SERVER_VERSION>1.0.388</SERVER_VERSION>
<PRE_PROCESSING_FILE_LOCATION/>
```

I have tried:

```
@Override
public void getProp(String prop) {
    try {
        final Document document = loadXMLFromString();
        document.getElementById(??);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Document loadXMLFromString() throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
    return builder.parse(is);
}
```

But I’m not sure how to get the node’s ID.

Is there any easier way? Maybe even string parsing is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no attribute `Id` defined in your xml element `SERVER_VERSION`. You can use `document.getElementByTagName("SERVER_VERSION")` to get the value.

Or use `XPath` to read the node:

```
final Document document = loadXMLFromString();
 XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
 XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();
 String xpathExpr="/result/SERVER_VERSION"; // assume result is the root node.
 Node node=(Node)xPath.compile(xpathExpr).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Comment: needed to find the root first "Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
            answer = root.getElementsByTagName(Constants.SERVER_VERSION).item(0).getTextContent();"